# Jquery captura ID da div no scroll e muda o título

Tags: jquery

Tenho uma página com um título e várias divs com assuntos diferentes e IDs próprias, gostaria que ao descer a tela, o jquery captura a ID que esta visivel e coloca no título.

Comment: Quando dizes "coloca no título" queres dizer no "<title>`dentro da `<head>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para pegar o primeiro ID usando jquery você teria poderia usar o código abaixo, que te traria um objeto:

código 1

```
$( 'tag[id!=""]:visible:first' );
```

Onde a tag seria onde o id esta. Se o id identifica uma div, então no lugar da tag vc coloca div. O mesmo para input.

Para modificar o título você pode usar o código:

código 2

```
$( 'title' ).text("novo título");
```

Caso a sua tag no código 1 fosse um input, então você implementar o código 2 da seguinte maneira. Ex:

```
$( 'title' ).text( $( 'input[id!=""]:visible:first' ).val() )
```

Se quiser você pode dar uma olhada na documentação do jquery